# WordPress Limit Search to Category of Current Post

Tags: php, wordpress, search, limit, search-form

I have a WP theme which uses its own searchform. As you can see in the code below, it is already set to search within the category when the search form is displayed in this category.

I have also set the search form to be displayed above single posts, but when I search in this form, I get results from all categories. I want the search form to search only within the category of that post.

I have searched everywhere but cannot find a solution. Thank you in advance!

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<?php // Check to see if category, if yes, then modify the search parameters ?>
<?php if ( is_category() ) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); ?>" />
<?php $stext = esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Search Knowledgebase for %s&hellip;', 'ipt_kb' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="search" class="search-field form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $stext; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s" />
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="ipt-icon-search"></span></button></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just replace `<?php echo esc_attr( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); ?>` with category id

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I have 30 categories and I need to be able to search within each category separately, so I actually need it to find out which category current post belongs to and search within that category. If I just add the category id, it will search only for that single category in all search forms on the website

Comment: does that categories comes in same taxonomy ?

Comment: no, but I can add custom taxonomies to the categories if this will help

Comment: can we maybe add 'or' to this part of code: <?php if ( is_category() ) : ?> so  that it checks if it is category or if post belongs to category?

Comment: no it wont let you check `if post belongs to category` this `is_category()` will only return boolean if it is a category or not.

Comment: can you please list the taxonomy and post types in which you want to search so i can write a query for search.

Comment: taxonomies are: `'diadora'`, `'iadera'`, `'borik'`, `'adriana'` and the only post type I used is `post`

Comment: please add it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit **`search.php`** and add below code.. loop over the result.

below code will search keyword with in defined taxonomies and its terms and the post type `post`

```
function getAllTermsByTaxonomy($taxonomy) {
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'fields'     => 'ids'
    ));
    return $taxonomy_terms;
}
// Get all term ID's in a given taxonomy
$terms_of_diadora = getAllTermsByTaxonomy('diadora');
$terms_of_iadera  = getAllTermsByTaxonomy('iadera');
$terms_of_borik   = getAllTermsByTaxonomy('borik');
$terms_of_adriana = getAllTermsByTaxonomy('adriana');
// Use the new `tax_query` WP_Query argument
$args  = array(
    's'         => get_query_var('s'),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'diadora',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms_of_diadora
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'iadera',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms_of_iadera,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'borik',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms_of_borik,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'adriana',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms_of_adriana,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
// Loop through the post
```

Comment: your welcome :) would be great if you upvote to answer :p

Comment: i did, but it said that i don't have enough credit to upvote you :/